# how to perform word clustering using k-means algorithm in java

Tags: java

Please help me how to perform word clustering using k-means algorithm in java. From the set of documents, I get word and its frequency count. Then i dont know how to start for clustering.I already search google. But no idea. Please tell me steps to perform word clustering. Very needful now. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should work on your accept-rate.

Answer (score 0):

["Programming Collective Intelligence"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596529325) by Toby Segaran has a wonderful chapter on how to do this.  The examples are in Python, but they should be easy to port to Java.

Answer (score 0):

In clustering most important thing is to build a method, which check how to things (for example) are "close" together. E.g. is you are interested in string with same lang, this could be like:

```
int calculateDistance(String s1, String s2) {
     return Math.abs(s1.length() - s2.length());
}
```

Then I'm not so sure, but in can be like this:
1. choose (can be randomly) first k string,
2. iterate for all string, and relate them to their "nearest" string.

Then can be something, like choosing from every "cluster" middle of it, and start it again. I don't remember it for 100% but I thing it is good way to start.

And remember, that most important is the method calculateDistance()!